# How to change indentation of a text block?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

It's probably a really basic question, but I'm just starting out with LaTeX. I want a, preferably elegant, solution for putting one block of text a bit more to the right than the rest of the text like so:[image]

Comment: `\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}`?

Comment: @Sigur Is there a way to change the size of the indentation there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `quoting` package and its eponymous environment give you full control on the layout of the environment (font, spacing w.r.t. the text, left and right margins, &c.) Here is a small demo:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %
 \usepackage{quoting} %
\usepackage{lipsum}
\quotingsetup{font={itshape}, leftmargin=2em, rightmargin=0in, vskip=1ex}

 \begin{document}

 \lipsum[2]
\begin{quoting}
Sed feugiat. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
 montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut pellentesque augue sed urna.
 Vestibulum diam eros, fringilla et, consectetuer eu, nonummy id,
 sapien. Nullam at lectus. In sagittis ultrices mauris. Curabitur
 malesuada erat sit amet massa. Fusce blandit. Aliquam erat volutpat.
 Aliquam euismod. Aenean vel lectus. Nunc imperdiet justo nec dolor.
\end{quoting}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Bernard can you remove, please, your previous comment? I have delete now mine that is off-topic for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following defines an environment `indentedblock` that allows you to indent it using `\leftskip` internally. The environment does suppress the indentation of the first line, if you want that line to be indented use `indentedblock*` instead. You can customize the left skip using an optional argument. It adds a bit of vertical space around itself. The following paragraph will be indented (you might suppress that by using `\noindent`).

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{indentedblock*}[1][\parindent]
  {%
    \par
    \medskip
    \leftskip#1\relax
  }
  {%
    \par
    \medskip
  }
\newenvironment{indentedblock}[1][\parindent]
  {%
    \csname indentedblock*\endcsname[{#1}]%
    \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading
  }
  {%
    \csname endindentedblock*\endcsname
  }
\makeatother

\usepackage{duckuments} % only for dummy content

\begin{document}
\blindduck
\begin{indentedblock}
  \blindduck
\end{indentedblock}
\begin{indentedblock*}[5cm]
  \blindduck
\end{indentedblock*}
\blindduck
\end{document}
```

[image]